# Limit supported screen sizes in the amazon app store

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I'm about to release a few apps for the Google Play store and the Amazon app store. One of these apps should only be shown in the app store for a screen size that is considered either `small` or `normal` and two others should only be shown in the app store for a screen size that is considered either `large` or `xlarge`.

I know I can use the `<compatible-screens>` element in the manifest file for the Google Play store, but will the same technique work for the Amazon app store? I've looked all over the amazon developer site, and read through [their FAQ](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html) three times and can't seem to find anything that would indicate either way.

If the `<compatible-screens>` method won't work for the Amazon app store, then is there something that will work for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a response from amazon, they said

> From an app manifest perspective, currently the expression builder uses the  portion and the sdk/os version of a given android app to build the expression. It does not leverage the following (newer) sections that provide more valuable input about the compatibility of the application.
>
> <uses-feature> : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html
>
> <supports-screen> : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html
>
> <compatible-screen> : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: Just found this SO Q&A after posting this - https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/84660/is-it-possible-to-control-device-support-through-a.html - on Amazon's forums.  Be interesting to hear if anything has changed 5 years on!